# Latitude Longitude is null outside LocationCallback

Tags: java, android, location, google-play-services

I am using google play services api to get location. I got the location in `LocationCallback` and I can update the UI also from inside the callback method. But when I want to store the lat, lng in another variable to it becomes 0. here is my code, what i am missing here?

```
FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
request.setInterval(5000);
request.setFastestInterval(2500);
request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

LocationCallback callback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();

            lattitude = lat;
            longitude = lng;

            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLat)).setText(String.valueOf(lat));
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLng)).setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        }
    }
};

client.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, null);
```

Comment: So, the `TextViews` are showing the correct value, but "...another variable to it becomes 0"?  Are you referring to the variables "lattitude"  and "longitude" ?  Where and how are they defined?

Comment: Hi @Barns yes the TextViews showing correct values. And yes lattitude & longitude are global variables.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to access those variables before the callback has assigned the actual expected values.

Comment: What are the data types of `lattitude` and `longitude`? And yes, where are you checking the values of these two items? I think you are trying to fetch their values before the values are set.